# How does jquery ajax actually work

Tags: jquery

Say I have a form like this (taken from a book on jquery):

```
<body>
<form>
<label>Enter your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="uname" class="uname"/> <br/>
<input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>
```

and an ajax function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submit').click(function () {
   var name = $('.uname').val();
   var data = 'uname=' + name;
      $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"welcome.php",
         data: data,
         success: function (html) {
            $('#message').html(html);
         }
      });
      return false;
   });
});
```

and the script file looks like this:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['uname'];
echo "Welcome ". $name;
?>
```

it will work but here's what I can't understand. If the welcome.php script gets the value of $name from the POST array, why does it need to have the data sent to it by the ajax request? The POST array already contains that information surely?

Also, my understanding is that the ajax request is in the form of key/value pairs but the data is sent in the form uname=name but key/value pairs don't normally have an equals sign.

What's going on here - it works but it doesn't make sense to me and I hate just punching in code I have learnt by rote.

Comment: jQuery hijacks your form submit, so the usual mechanism for filling in `POST` data doesn't happen. jQuery instead sends its own data, which can be anything, and in this case that is your form field.

Comment: `return false;` makes it so the form doesn't submit. `ajax` sends the data to the server and receives a response in the `success function`. This allows us to mimic the form submit without the page refreshing.

Comment: Where else would the php get the form value from except from the post data? That's what the POST array *is*.

Comment: "key/value pairs don't normally have an equals sign" - that's how they're specified for application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: do a web search for `xmlHttpRequest` which is what AJAX is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with your code 
 **var data = 'uname=' + name;**
 use
 **var data = '{uname:' + name + '}';** 
 because its a post method

Answer (score 2):

jQuery AJAX works asynchronously. The form does not get posted, as you can see it does not have an action or method attribute set on the form tag.

jQuery intercepts the button click and sets up a new asynchronous request and then adds the data to that request and posts it to the server.