# How is jQuery capturing the PHP response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

As you can see, this code takes the values from the forms, and put them in the database. Depending on the outcome, it returns either "False" or "Success!".

The only thing I can't understand, is how this jQuery function is displaying the outcome without having to reload the page. 'Info' is not attached to anything in the PHP file.

PHP source:
    include_once('db.php'); 
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $age = $_POST['age'];

```
        $query = $conn->query("INSERT INTO user VALUES('$name','$age')");

        if($query) {
            echo 'Success!';
        } else {
            echo 'Fail';    
        }
```

Javascript source

```
$("#sub").click(function(){
    $.post(
        $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
        function(info){
        $("#result").html(info);
    }); 
    clearInput();
});
```

Comment: because that's how ajax works

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004867/how-does-jquery-ajax-actually-work

Comment: This is also a good link: https://tle.wisc.edu/blend/facilitate/communicate

Answer (score 5):

Read up a little on [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) as well as [.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Basically, an Ajax request means that the Javascript performs a new request to the server, without having to reload the page. Typically it loads a special page that only contains JSON or XML data, but it can be in whatever format you like. This is useful for updating the page content without modifying anything else on the page. Lots of websites use this, so learning it would be helpful for any future web development that you might do.

In the code, `info` is a parameter for the success callback of the XMLHttpRequest request to the server. It will be populated with the data returned from the *background* request to the PHP server.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtful answer. Actually, I wasn't as clear as I expected in my question: I am aware of the AJAX asynchronous characteristics, but I didn't know how it was returning the PHP outcome (which thanks to you, now I do).

Answer (score 2):

> The only thing I can't understand, is how this jQuery function is displaying the outcome without having to reload the page.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming) & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

> With Ajax, Web applications can send data to, and retrieve data from, a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page. Data can be retrieved using the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: I believe I have made myself unclear: I am aware of the asynchronous characteristic of AJAX, I was not understanding how it was intercepting PHP, which now I do. Thank You.